# std::enable_shared_from_this: no known conversion from a to a

Tags: c++, c++11, this, shared-ptr

I have a class `VectorSpace` with a member `createVector()` which creates a `Vector` with a shared pointer to the referencing `VectorSpace`. This is achieved by `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

However, this following code

```
#include <memory>

class Vector;
class VectorSpace;

class Vector {
public:
  Vector(std::shared_ptr<VectorSpace> & space):
    space_(space)
  {
  };

private:
  std::shared_ptr<VectorSpace> space_;
};

class VectorSpace: std::enable_shared_from_this<VectorSpace> {
  public:
  VectorSpace(){};

  Vector
  createMember()
  {
    return Vector(shared_from_this());
  };

};

int main() {
  auto space = std::make_shared<VectorSpace>();
  Vector x(space);
}
```

*fails* with compile with the very strange error message

```
test.cpp:8:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::shared_ptr<VectorSpace>’ to ‘std::shared_ptr<VectorSpace>’
```

(This is with GCC 4.9.2.)

What's the deal here?

Comment: try removing & in Vector constructor: shared_from_this creates new shared_ptr

Comment: @Hcorg just noticed your comment. You might consider making this type of thing an answer - it solves the problem.

Comment: I can tell you have edited the error messages, because you didn't show an error.  You only copied a **note** on an error.  Please don't hide error messages.  They aren't supposed to be secret!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
Vector(std::shared_ptr<VectorSpace> & space):
                                   ^^^
```

The `Vector` constructor takes an lvalue reference, but in `createMember()` you're passing in an rvalue:

```
  Vector
  createMember()
  {
    return Vector(shared_from_this());
  };
```

Just drop the `&`. For what it's worth, I don't have access to gcc 4.9.2, but on 5.1.0 at least the error message is pretty clear:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'Vector VectorSpace::createMember()':

main.cpp:24:35: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::shared_ptr<VectorSpace>&' from an rvalue of type 'std::shared_ptr<VectorSpace>'

     return Vector(shared_from_this());    
                                   ^
```

The second issue in your code is:

```
class VectorSpace: std::enable_shared_from_this<VectorSpace> {
```

As [Angew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732281/stdenable-shared-from-this-no-known-conversion-from-a-to-a/30732405?noredirect=1#comment49521274_30732405) points out, you need to inherit from `enable_shared_from_this` publicly.

Comment: Now it says: `error: ‘std::enable_shared_from_this<VectorSpace>’ is an inaccessible base of ‘VectorSpace’`. Is this any different on GCC 5.1?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer You need to use public inheritance for `enable_shared_from_this`.